# Displaying separate data from API in different places on page in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

I have a SPA that will display data from an API in two separate parts of the page. One section displays products and prices. This information will remain on the page. The other section is a basic CRUD view. It allows the user to create new selections, read their selections, edit their selections, and remove their selections. I'm trying to determine the best way to display these two views. The CRUD section uses ng-view. Should the price/product section use a directive, a separate controller, or should I break up the page into two modules?

I'm new to Angular, and want to make sure that I do things right to avoid unforeseen issues down the road.

HTML:

```
<div ng-view="">
<!--user selections go here -->
</div>

<!--Product/Price info will go here. Unsure whether to insert ng-app="new module", ng-controller="new controller", or a directive with its own element-->
```

Javascript for user selections view:

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider

    .when('/list', {
        templateUrl: 'views/list.html',
        controller: 'ProjectListCtrl as projectList'
    })
    .when('/edit/:projectId', {
        templateUrl: 'views/detail.html',
        controller: 'EditProjectCtrl as editProject'
    })
    .when('/new', {
        templateUrl: 'views/detail.html',
        controller: 'NewProjectCtrl as editProject'
    })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });

 });
```

Factory for CRUD / user form section:

```
myApp.factory('Projects', function($firebase, fbURL) {
return $firebase(new Firebase(fbURL+'/projects')).$asArray();
});
```

Factory for product list/price section:

```
myApp.factory('Products', function($firebase, fbURL) {
return $firebase(new Firebase(fbURL + '/products')).$asArray();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native Angular router is limited when creating complex and nested UIs, but [AngularUI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) is a great alternative and very widely used. If you want to include multiple views in your interface then this is the way to go. It's not much more complicated than the native router but the wins are huge.

> AngularUI Router is a routing framework for AngularJS, which allows you to organize the parts of your interface into a state machine. Unlike the $route service in the Angular ngRoute module, which is organized around URL routes, UI-Router is organized around states, which may optionally have routes, as well as other behavior, attached.

**Here's a Plunker to demo your particular case:** http://plnkr.co/edit/xZD47L?p=preview

With ui-router you can name views

```
<div ui-view="viewName"></div>
```

and include templates and controllers in the corresponding ui-router configuration

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  // For any unmatched url, redirect to /
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
  $stateProvider
    .state('home',{
      url: "/",
      // list your views
      views: {
        "viewName": { 
          templateUrl: "viewName.html" ,
          controller: "viewNameCtrl"
        }
      }
   })
});
```

Checkout this Wiki for [Multiple Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views).

I hope this helps.